# HTTP Request without using Browser

Tags: java, http, jar, httprequest, httpresponse

I am working on a application which allows user to download JARs which is actually a PDF player displaying some PDFs which are downloaded as a part of JAR itself.

Now whenever users clicks on that JAR File, I want to validate the PDF Bundle on the server (whether it got expired? Or a new version is available). Also, I want my PDF Content to get updated if a new version of the downloaded bundle is available. So I will need to download the PDFs from the server if a new version is there.

So I want to make a HTTP Request to the server from inside my JAR & receive some PDFs (and some additional data as well) as response.

Any idea how I can do this? Is there some API available for creating HTTP Requests from a plain Java Program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an HTTP request by creating a URL and getting the connection for it, and casting it to HttpURLConnection.

Add an "If-Modified-Since" header, with the download date of your local file. If the server responds with 304 (not modified), then your local version is up-to-date.

If the local version is not up-to-date, the server will respond with the actual content, which you use to update your local cache.

Comment: Thanks for the 304 status information. That will really help in keeping it efficient & fast.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HttpUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). it should do the task.

Answer (score 1):

For raw binary data I use;

```
public static byte[] getContent(String s) {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(s);
        URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
        //we lie, java user-agents are sometimes blacklisted
        c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MSIE 7.0");
        InputStream r = c.getInputStream();
        String ret = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r));
        for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) ret += line;
        return ret.getBytes();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return new byte[0];
}
```

Which can then be piped onto a `FileOutputStream` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by a couple of others, you can use an HttpUrlConnection.  However, there's still a fair amount (not a lot, but a fair amount) of work.

Alternatively, check out [basic-http-client](http://code.google.com/p/basic-http-client/).  Actually, since that is open source, check it out even if you plan to write your own code, to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
try {
  //Create connection
  url = new URL(targetURL);
  connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  .....

  //Send request
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
  wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
  .......

  //Get Response
  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  ....read the contents
 }catch(...){
   ...
 }
```